# How to implement MVC using Julia, Genie.jl and Oracle.jl?

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller, julia

Code to connect and insert data, as follows:

```
struct person
    person_id::Int
    person_name::String
    person_mobile_phone::String
    person_email::String
end

import Oracle

global const dbHost = "localhost";
global const dbClientType = "thin";
global const dbName = "xe";
global const dbPort = "1521";
global const dbUserName = "ava";
global const dbUserPassword = "ava";
global const conn_str="//"*dbHost*":"*dbPort*"/"*dbName;


function prepare_connection()
global conn = Oracle.Connection(dbUserName, dbUserPassword, conn_str);
global txn_insert_query = "INSERT INTO ava.person(person_id, person_name, person_mobile_phone, person_email) VALUES (:person_id, :person_name, :person_mobile_phone, :person_email)"
end

function close_connection()
Oracle.close(conn);
end
  
function insert_person(person_id::String, person_name::String, person_mobile_phone::String, person_email::String)
prepare_connection()
txn_insert_stmt = Oracle.Stmt(conn, txn_insert_query)
txn_insert_stmt[:person_id] = parse(Int, person_id);
txn_insert_stmt[:person_name] = person_name;
txn_insert_stmt[:person_mobile_phone] = person_mobile_phone;
txn_insert_stmt[:person_email] = person_email;
Oracle.execute(txn_insert_stmt);
Oracle.close(txn_insert_stmt)
Oracle.commit(conn)
close_connection()
end

prepare_connection()

using Genie, Genie.Router, Genie.Renderer.Html, Genie.Requests

down()

form = """
<form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="person_id" value="" placeholder="What's your id?" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="person_name" value="" placeholder="What's your name?" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="person_mobile_phone" value="" placeholder="What's your mobile phone number?" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="person_email" value="" placeholder="What's your email?" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
"""

route("/") do
  html(form)
end

route("/", method = POST) do
insert_person(postpayload(:person_id), postpayload(:person_name), postpayload(:person_mobile_phone), postpayload(:person_email))
end

up()
```

Please guide me in restructuring the above code with MVC architechture.

Comment: Please elaborate what specifically you are looking for and having problems with. "Make this MVC" -> needs more focus. (Also, MVC is not a universally known term.)